# Integrate Angular Material theme into existing ngx-admin project

Tags: angular, angular-material, nebular, ngx-admin

In the ngx-admin material theme branch they say:

> Already using ngx-admin and willing to switch to material theme?
> Material theme is backward-compatible. Check out the article
> describing how to do that.

Where is the article that talk about that?

Or do you guys manage to integrate material theme into existing ngx-admin project?

Is there a better solution to integrate all module and package manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to use their theme engine too with Angular material, then you would be better off to get a fresh cloned copy of the latest ngx-admin and copy over your feature modules and components into it than to try and figure out every piece needed to have the theme switching updating the material components.

We have a fairly large angular application using ngx-admin and each time they release a new angular version (they just updated their template to angular 12). We get a fresh copy of their template and copy over our feature modules into it. We didn't do any major customization of their template either so it is easier for us to do that.

Comment: Thx, i actually gonna do that.